# Complex limit without L'Hospital Rule

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

How would one eveluate the following limit without using L'Hospital Rule
$$\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{e^{\Delta z^2+2z\Delta z}-1}{\Delta z}$$
where $\Delta z=\Delta x+i\Delta y\,$ and $z=x+iy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by standard limit

$$x\to 0 \qquad \frac{e^x-1}{x}\to 1$$

we simply have

$$\frac{e^{\Delta z^2+2z\Delta z}-1}{\Delta z}=\frac{e^{\Delta z^2+2z\Delta z}-1}{\Delta z^2+2z\Delta z}\frac{\Delta z^2+2z\Delta z}{\Delta z}=\frac{e^{\Delta z^2+2z\Delta z}-1}{\Delta z^2+2z\Delta z}{(\Delta z+2z)}\to2z$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor expansion, we see that
\begin{align}
\exp((\Delta z + 2z)\Delta z) = 1+(\Delta z+2z)\Delta z+\frac{1}{2}(\Delta z+2z)^2\Delta z^2+\ldots
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{\exp((\Delta z + 2z)\Delta z)-1}{\Delta z} = (\Delta z+2z)+\frac{1}{2}(\Delta z+2z)^2\Delta z+\ldots
\end{align}
As $\Delta z\rightarrow 0$, then it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{\Delta z \rightarrow 0}\frac{\exp(\Delta z^2 + 2z\Delta z)-1}{\Delta z}=2z.
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer essentially use De L'Hopital, which is not allowed, doesn't it?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco No, I did not use L’Hopital. Also, I don’t know of any complex version of L’Hopital.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience of notation, let $h=\Delta z$.

Let $f(z)=e^{z^2}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h^2+2zh}-1}{h}\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\frac{1}{e^{z^2}}\right)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left(e^{z^2}\right)\left(e^{h^2+2zh}-1\right)}{h}\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\frac{1}{e^{z^2}}\right)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h^2+2zh+z^2}-e^{z^2}}{h}\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\frac{1}{e^{z^2}}\right)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{(z+h)^2}-e^{z^2}}{h}\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\frac{1}{e^{z^2}}\right)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\frac{1}{e^{z^2}}\right)f'(z)\\[4pt]
=\;&
\left(\frac{1}{e^{z^2}}\right)\left(2ze^{z^2}\right)\\[4pt]
=\;&2z\\[4pt]
\end{align*}